# Go Channels in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ipc, go, channel

In the Go programming language, you can send Messages around using a construct called "Channels".
http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels

I would love to use something like that in Ruby, especially for IPC.

Pseudocode of what I want:

```
channel = Channel.new

fork do
  3.times{ channel.send("foo ") }
  exit!
end

Thread.new do
  3.times{ channel.send("bar ") }
end

loop do
  print channel.recv
end

# ~> bar foo foo bar bar foo
```

Is there any construct, library or equivalent for Ruby which works like that ?

If not: What is the best way to build such an abstraction?

**UPDATE:** To clarify what I need from these Channels.

One use case: Some forked workers waiting for jobs. They all read from the same JobChannel and report results to the same ResultChannel.

The Channels I need

- are very fast,
- writes do not block, *(message sending)*
- reads do block, *(message receiving)*
- do not need special treatment before forking,
- lightweight and simple would be nice.

So far I played around with

- DRb, *(opposite of lightweight + slow + too much magic for my little brain)*
- Sockets, *(UNIXSocket, TCPSocket ... Sockets seem to have many many ways of using them. I got a half-working channel on UNIXSockets. If you think sockets make sense, what subset of features should I look at?)*
- Pipes. *(Connecting more than 2 Processes seems to be non-trivial)*

If any of those was already the perfect technology for my problem, please provide tutorials etc. which have more focused information on my requirements.

Comment: is this something like pipes or shared memory ?. For what purpose do you need such a thing. the channel it seems is sending information and receiving it itself ?

Comment: @Rishav Rastogi: No, Go Channels are much more like, well, like Channels. Go's Channels are based on Newsqueak's Channels (not surprisingly, since Newsqueak was designed by Rob Pike), which in turn are a hybrid between CSP Channels (the later version, obviously, not the original one) and π-Calculus Channels. I believe Occam might also have been an influence.

Answer (score 1):

Go's idea of message passing via channels, as a first-class construct, really only makes sense in the presence of concurrency (goroutines, tasklets, whatever you'd care to call them). With cheap concurrency, blocking a tasklet or coroutine is no longer a problem, and blocking message passing starts to make a lot more sense.

If this were Python, I'd point you at [Stackless](http://www.stackless.com/); in Ruby, perhaps [Revactor](http://revactor.org/) or [NeverBlock](http://www.espace.com.eg/neverblock) fit the bill for you?

Comment: Thanks. All those concurrency concepts are fairly new to me. Actors might solve what I am looking for. 
For Ruby 1.8, I will try the Omnibus library. http://github.com/mental/concurrent

Comment: Damn, Omnibus actors spawn as green threads. They have a concept of message passing, which they call "Mailbox". I want exactly that Mailbox just for usage across multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

check out this question:
[shared-variable-among-ruby-processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057120/shared-variable-among-ruby-processes)

and also check out [drb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/drb/rdoc/classes/DRb.html)

Hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout agent gem, it has a syntax close to what you wnat: https://github.com/igrigorik/agent

Answer (score 0):

[Cod](https://github.com/kschiess/cod) is a gem for IPC using channels.